# The command of the plug-in I created does not work

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am creating a Minecraft plugin in Eclipce 2020.
I'd like to be able to change the game mode by entering ./gm , which is a shortened game mode, but it's not completed.
When I set up a server in the local environment and entered ./gm ..., the game mode was changed once and there was evidence that the game mode was changed to Creative .... Avdenture, Spectator ... mode.
There is. How can I do this?
By the way, I'm new to creating plugins. Thank you.

```
---Main.java
package jp.mm5.b1325;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("AdminTool is Enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("AdminTool is Disable");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd , String lobel , String[] args) {
        if(sender instanceof Player){
           Player p = (Player) sender;
           if(p.hasPermission("admin.gm")){
             if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm")) {
                 if(args[0].equals("0"))
                 {
                   p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
                   p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to survival");
                   return true;
                 }
                 if(args[1].equals("0"))
                 {
                   p.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
                   p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to creative");
                   return true;
                 }
            }
          }
        return false;
  }
}



---plugin.yml
name: AdminTool
main: jp.mm5.b1325.Main
version: 0.2
author: mi5

commands:
  gm:
    description: aa
    usage: /<command>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is, that you trying to compare your input with the length of the arguments of the command. What you want to do is

```html
if(args[0].equals("0"))
```

This checks if the first argument is 0 or 1, etc.

The next thing is that your if statements are missing braces. I am not sure what you are trying to do with the "return false;" after the if statements but I recommend you to delete these.
So the survival if statement should look like this:

```html
if(args[0].equals("0"))
{
    p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
    p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to survival");
    return true;
}
```

Now adept this for the other gamemodes and everything should be working.

Edit:
Your onCommand function should look like this.

```html
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd , String lobel , String[] args)
    {
        if(sender instanceof Player)
        {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            if(p.hasPermission("admin.gm")){
                if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm"))
                {

                    if(args[0].equals("0"))
                    {
                        p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
                        p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to survival");
                        return true;
                    }

                    else if(args[0].equals("1"))
                    {
                        p.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
                        p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to creative");
                        return true;
                    }

                    else if(args[0].equals("2"))
                    {
                        p.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
                        p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to adventure");
                        return true;
                    }

                    else if(args[0].equals("3"))
                    {
                        p.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
                        p.sendMessage("Game mode changed to spectator");
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: not work. if(args[1].equals("0")) Even if I typed it like this, only survival responded and I could not change it to creative

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste your current source code into it?

Comment: ok you changed the index of the args. What you have to do is change the number in the string which you compare to the argument. So for creative it's args[0].equals("1") and for adventure it's args[0].equals("2")

Comment: I tried it and only ./gm 0 responded, but the others did not.
When I added return false; to the if (args [0] .equals ("number")) described in each if statement, it was displayed that there was a syntax error in else.
Also, when return false; is deleted, if (args [0], equals ("1")) {p.setGameMode (GameMode.CREATIVE); to return true} is displayed as an unreachable code.

Comment: The source code for else is else {p.sendMessage ("You have to permission!")}

Comment: Ok I edited my answer and included the whole onCommand function and how it should look like. I think your main problem is that you try to code plugins but you don't know how to code java. I highly recommend you to learn java before starting to program plugins.